# Splitting a string into different data types

Tags: vb.net

If I have a string such as:

```
Bridport, Dorset, 12977, 425
```

Is there a way to use the split function so I can declare the first two parts as strings and the last two parts as integers?

Comment: Splitting on the comma would make an array, then create variables and you can cast the types from there.

Comment: the string's parts are still strings, use Convert or Cint [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27080237/1070452)

Comment: I tried doing that but it said that the input format was not valid

Comment: examine the CSV file with a text editor - you may have wrecked it using Put and Get and expecting a CSV format to be preserved.

Comment: Is there a way to start the statements within a loop from the second time it is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it into a `String()`, then use `Int32.Parse` to parse the last two into integers.

```
Dim tokens = text.Split(","c)
Dim part1 As String = tokens(0).Trim()
Dim part2 As String = tokens(1).Trim()
Dim part3 As Int32  = Int32.Parse(tokens(2).Trim())
Dim part4 As Int32  = Int32.Parse(tokens(3).Trim())
```

If you don't know if the format is valid  you can use this super-safe version:

```
Dim part1 As String = tokens(0).Trim()
Dim part2 As String = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(1)
If part2 IsNot Nothing Then part2 = part2.Trim()
Dim part3 As String = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(2)
Dim part4 As String = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(3)
Dim num1 As Int32? = New Nullable(Of Int32)
Dim num2 As Int32? = New Nullable(Of Int32)
If part3 IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim num As Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(part3.Trim(), num) Then
        num1 = num
    End If
End If
If part4 IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim num As Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(part4.Trim(), num) Then
        num2 = num
    End If
End If
```

I'm using a `Nullable(Of Integer)` to know whether or not the string could be parsed to `Integer` successfully. It has  `HasValue` and `Value` properties. Use the latter if `HasValue` returns `True`.

Comment: Using that it still says that the input format was not valid

Comment: @Todd432: i have edited my answer to provide a safe approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim info as string = "Bridport,Dorset,12977,425"
Dim split as string() = info.split(",")
Dim string1 as string = split(0) ' Reads Bridport
Dim string2 as string = split(1) ' Reads Dorset
Dim int1 as integer = split(2) ' Reads 12977
Dim int2 as integer = split(3) ' Reads 425
```

Comment: You really should use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).